# SwiftUI remove white color when context menu opens

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to use context menu is SwiftUI and I faced into the issue that white background appears during
How can I remove white background ?

```
struct PlayerLayerView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/2f4ipZX.mp4")!))
            .contextMenu {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("item")
                }
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("item")
                }
            } preview: {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/2f4ipZX.mp4")!))
            }
      
    }
}

#Preview {
    PlayerLayerView()
}
```

[video example](https://i.imgur.com/eVa3QTF.mp4)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the white background is not seen if the context menu is attached to an overlay. The trouble is, if the overlay covers the full area then it also blocks all gestures, so it prevents interaction with the video player.

I tried using the following overlay consisting of transparent areas to allow gestures to pass through in places:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Color.clear.frame(height: 50)
    Color.white.opacity(0.001)
    Color.clear.frame(height: 50)
    Color.white.opacity(0.001)
    Color.clear.frame(height: 50)
}
```

This worked, but it still wasn't satisfactory because you want to be able to tap the paused video anywhere in order to get the controls to show.

However, I found that a small button-like control works quite well. It can also be labelled to make it clear what its purpose is:

```swift
VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/2f4ipZX.mp4")!))
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        Text("Hold for preview")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(.gray.opacity(0.5))
            }
            .contentShape(.contextMenuPreview, Capsule())
            .padding(50)
            .contextMenu {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("item")
                }
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("item")
                }
            } preview: {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/2f4ipZX.mp4")!))
            }
    }
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Yep, I did almost the same. I'm using `ZStack` with player and  `Color.white.opacity(0.001)` as the top level which show context menu, and it works, and of course I'm not able to use player control buttons. 
Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the `contextMenu` modifier creates a context menu with a default background. You need to use a combine of custom views and gestures to mimic a context menu without a background.